# Use matrix build in Travis only on deploy

Tags: build, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is there any way to *only* run a matrix build in travis on deploy? Right now we use the same `.travis.yml` file for test and deploy, and a matrix build (and thus two workers) is triggered in both cases. I can't find a way to only run the build as a matrix in the case in which we are deploying and not when we are running tests (or perhaps to only use a matrix during the deploy process). The main reason I'd like to do this is so that I don't trigger extra builds when PRs are created and I just need the test build to run.

I also couldn't find a simple way we could run a single build for npm install/npm test and then spin off two separate workers/a matrix for the "deploy" process, which would also solve the problem.

Here's a snip of my current .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js
node_js: 4.2.1
env:
  global:
    - APP_NAME=example
  matrix:
    - CF_DOMAIN=example1.net CF_TARGET=https://target1.com APP_NAME=${APP_NAME}-1
    - CF_DOMAIN=example2.net CF_TARGET=https://target2.com APP_NAME=${APP_NAME}-2

branches:
  only:
    - master
deploy:
- provider: script
  skip_cleanup: true
  script: node_modules/.bin/deploy.sh
  on:
    branch: master
```

It might also work for us to only run a matrix build on a `push` hook, but not on a `pr`.

Answer (score 2):

There was a similar issue posted in GitHub for Travis. It was suggested to use two separate .travis.yml files.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2778

Comment: Right, two configurations in two branches would deploy to two separate places and could have different behavior, but I don't want to maintain the same piece of code in two places along with two different configuration files. I would expect that it would be possible to have a single configuration file to indicate that a matrix build should be run as part of a `push`, but not as part of a `pr`.